# Web LiveStreaming WebRTC and Sockets (Flask Backend)

Tags: flask, webrtc, getusermedia, flask-socketio

I want to build a live streaming app.
My thought process:

1. Get the Video/Audio data from the
    `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);` [client-streamer]
2. create rooms using sockets(Socket.IO or WebSockets from flask) [backend]
3. Send the data in 1 to the room members using sockets.
4. display the media on the client-side.

Is that correct? How should I do it?

how do I broadcast data to specific room members and not to everyone? (flask)
How to consistently send data from the streamer -> server -> room members. the stream is given from 1 is an object, where is the data?

any other better ideas will be great! thanks.

- I need to implement the server-side by myself without help from libraries that will do the work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing a streaming platform is not trivial. Unfortunately, it is not as simple as emitting chunks received from the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) with `onndatavailable` and forwarding them to users using a WebSocket server - this is not scalable nor efficient nor reliable.

Below are some strategies you can try for different types of scenarios:

**P2P**: If you want to have simple peer-to-peer streaming, you can use [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) to achieve that with a simple socket.io server for [signaling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_signaling.htm) purposes.

**Conference**: Here things start to get more complicated. You will need a media server if you want to be somewhat scalable. One approach is to route your stream to the users using an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) or [MCU](https://webrtcglossary.com/mcu/). This will take care of forwarding/processing media to different peers efficiently.

**Broadcast**: Here things are also non-trivial. Common WebRTC-based architectures include ingesting the WebRTC stream and forward that to an [HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) server which will let your stream chunks available for clients through a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), or perform [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) forwarding of the WebRTC stream, convert it to [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol) using something like [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and deliver it through Youtube Live or Twitch to leverage from their infrastructure.

Be aware that the last 2 items are resource-intensive and will certainly **not** be cheap to maintain.

Below are some open source projects that could help you along the way:

- [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/index.html)
- [MediaSoup](https://mediasoup.org/)
- [AntMedia](https://antmedia.io/)
- [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I already have tried the Broadcast (RTMP/HLS) method and it did not go well. Does P2P work with only 2 people in one call? like a video call?

Comment: Yes. You can probably get up to 4 people in a call, no more than that.
Check out this sample app using P2P strategy that supports more than 2 people: https://github.com/lnogueir/webrtc-socketio-sample

Answer (score 0):

Explaining all this is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Here are a few hints:

1. You need to use the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to capture compressed data from your gUM (getUserMedia) stream. MediaRecorder support is inconsistent between makes and models of browser. though.
2. It kicks a Blob into its `onndatavailable` handler every so often.
   They're compressed as a [webm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/webm) data stream.
3. You can push those Blobs to a server with socket.io, and the server can turn around and push them to whatever clients you want to.
4. Playing the webm on the clients is tricky. You may, on some makes and models of browsers, be able to feed the webm stream to the [Media Source API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) using [appendBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/appendBuffer). But some browsers cannot consume the webm streams.
5. These webm streams are useless to a player without all their Blob data in order. You can't just start sending a new client the Blobs of the stream when they sign in; you have to restart the MediaRecorder.
6. (You may be able to make it work without a MediaRecorder restart if you send the first few k bytes of the stream to each new client before sending the current Blob. Extracting those bytes is an intricate programming job involving the [ebml package](https://mediasoup.org/) to parse the webm stream and extract the prologue. I have not proven this concept.)
7. Because getting all this to work -- originator -- server -- viewer is such a pain in the xxx neck, you may want to investigate using something like [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) instead. It uses WebRTC transport rather than socket.io, and works cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it.